# Get last command in error trap in zsh

Tags: zsh

This function should show the last command when an error has occurred:

```bash
TRAPZERR() {             
  cmd=$_         
  echo command \'$cmd\' had an error    
}
```

`$_` just gives the last argument.

```
$ false true
command 'true' had an error
```

This is for a script.